# Why is my content missing from homepage?

Tags: posts

On my website http://filmblurb.org, all the posts and everything on my home page are missing. Can you anybody tell me how to fix this?

Thanks! (If it helps, I'm using Wordpress 3.2.1.)

Comment: Close-voted as *not a real question*.

Comment: I have also voted to close this as not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any missing content. Are you sure you weren't just having server issues at the time of posting this? Did you check it in other browsers? Having said that, this is not a real question and I have voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

I can see everything fine.

-try clearing cache in your browser before viewing the updated page. To clear cache in your browser, press clrl+f5 keys simultaneously. Also, try different computer/different browser.